# Maximum discount coupon

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon

how to limit the maximum percent amount for a coupon in magento.
For eg: Cart value is 3,50,000 
Coupon Code discount applicable : 20% 
So the discount will now be: 70,000.

But i want to restrict the discount amount to only 50000 max.

Please suggest configuration or code change how can it be done.